# Inner async not working in Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm relatively new to reactive programming and I'm trying to create an Angular service which can display notifications to the user. So far this is what I have:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-notifications?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

But I noticed that when you click the "Queue Notification" button my `*ngIf="message$ | async"` `<div>` appears correctly but the inner `{{ message$ | async }}` text doesn't appear unless you click the button twice in a row *without* clicking "Clear"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you split this into two separate questions? The second one definitely deserves a thread of its own.

Comment: @TomaszKula Done.

Comment: Link to the second question?

Comment: @TomaszKula https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907996/user-notification-service-with-rxjs-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem can be solved like this.

```
<div *ngIf="message$ | async as messages" >
  <div>{{ messages }}</div>
</div>
```

We store the result from the pipe in a local variable called `messages`. This way you avoid a situation in which the inner `async` pipe is not called after the outer one emits.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-notifications-xmlfuz)

Comment: I see that your live demo is working but unfortunately in my actual application I am using a third-party popup component where my template looks like this `<dx-popup [visible]="message$ | async as message">` with `{{ message }}` inside that. Is this `as` operator something special only to `*ngIf`?

Comment: Yes, the `as` is only allowed in `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`. Wrap your component in `<ng-container *ngIf="message$ | async as message">` and pass the `message` as the input.

Comment: Glad I could help :)