# User notification service with rxjs in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm relatively new to reactive programming and I'm trying to create an Angular service which can display notifications to the user. So far this is what I have:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-notifications?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

But there is a major problem with my implementation that I don't know how to solve: How, in a *reactive* way, can I queue up notifications? I would like my notification `div` to appear when the first notification is pushed and when the user clicks "Clear" I would like the div to disappear unless other notifications have been pushed since. That way clear would show the next notification and so on until all notifications have been cleared. Then as soon as a new notification is pushed the div should pop up again.

I chose a `Subject` in my implementation over a `ReplaySubject` because I don't want users to see notifications that were pushed while they were loading the next screen but I realized that if I'm using a router inside my `app.component.html` then I'll run into that behavior anyways. Maybe I need to clear the notification queue when a routing occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example service can look like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { map, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

enum ActionType {
  push = 'push',
  pop = 'pop'
}

interface Action {
  type: ActionType;
}

interface PushAction extends Action {
  payload: string;
}

interface PopAction extends Action { }

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  messages$: Observable<string[]>;

  private pushSource = new Subject<string>();
  private popSource = new Subject<void>();

  constructor() {
    const push$ = this.pushSource.asObservable()
      .pipe(map((payload) => ({ type: ActionType.push, payload })));

    const pop$ = this.popSource.asObservable()
      .pipe(map((payload) => ({ type: ActionType.pop })));

    this.messages$ = merge(push$, pop$)
      .pipe(
      scan((acc: any, { payload, type }) => {
        if (type === ActionType.pop) {
          acc = acc.slice(0, -1);
        }
        if (type === ActionType.push) {
          acc = [...acc, payload]
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
      )
  }

  pushMessage(msg: string) {
    this.pushSource.next(msg)
  }

  popMessage() {
    this.popSource.next()
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-notifications-ygate7)

We have two streams, `pop$` and `push$` that we merge together. We than reduce it into a single array using the `scan` operator.

So a stream of
`push(hello) -> push(world) -> pop -> push(kitty)` would be reduced to `[hello, kitty]`.

Comment: I am still wrapping my head around this (again, I am a reactive newbie) but I have some questions: 1. In your implementation the message appears as an array of all of the messages in the queue. Is it possible just to show the *first* message? Then when Clear is pressed, show the next message, and so on? 2. As the application runs and time goes on, would `pushSource` and `popSource` continue to grow in size indefinitely?

Comment: They would grow in size, but it really shouldn't be as issue. You will never see any performance penalty because of that. I assume you would never have 10000 notifications queued up.  To get the first element you can always add another map to the end of the operator's pipeline `map(list => list[0])`

Comment: You can manipulate the `messages$` stream just like you would any other array. Want to show the first element? Just get the element at index 0. You can have the `selectedId` as the local component state. Unwrap your observable, get the array, and use your selectedId to get  the correct item.

Comment: (1/2) I am learning a lot here, I approached this feature with a reactive methodology because I thought I might be able to use an Observable of a Subject in order to act as the method of change detection between the service and my top-level app component. But I think I was wrong to assume that an Observable of a Subject could act as a sort of iterator over a message queue but unlike an iterator in that it would emit empty when the queue is empty.

Comment: (2/2) Your implementation definitely achieves the functionality I wanted but it feels to me that I might be trying to shoehorn rxjs into this situation where it might not be warranted. Would you consider me trying to use rxjs here to be a misuse of reactive programming?

Comment: I think this is a great spot to use reactive programming . After all you do have a a stream of values generated over time.  You can modify the stream to do some cool stuff, like generating history of notification snapshots your user generates, as he pushes and pops the notifcations. `const history$ = this.messages$.pipe(scan((acc: any, curr) => [...acc, curr],[]))`

Comment: Thank you, you have been extremely helpful. I have one more question, you mentioned that I could add another `map` to the pipeline in your first comment and I'm trying that now but the object coming into that map function is an `any` type object. What type of object would it actually be at this point? Is there a way to make it typesafe too?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Check out this fork with $first, $last, and $all streams. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-notifications-k5gcq3